# Doxygen 1.8.8 : latex: dead links to source code

Tags: pdf, latex, doxygen

Doxygen has an option `LATEX_SOURCE_CODE`, if it is turned on, source code is included in the latex output; otherwise, sources aren't included, but resulting pdf file contains dead links, right after detailed description:

> Definition in file tn_mutex.h

Where `tn_mutex.h` is a dead link. It seems to me as a bug in the doxygen, but is there a way to work around this problem?

**UPD:** Bugzilla refuses to accept my bugreport (When I've pressed "confirm", I've waited a lot, and firefox returned "Unable to connect"), so I'm explaining it here.

Here's very simple C header file: `test.h`

```
/**
 * \file
 *
 * This is test header
 */

/**
 * test function, very useful btw
 */
void test_function(void);
```

And the doxyfile: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RfTYbTrP

(You can download ready-made archive with these files: http://dfrank.ru/usr/tmp/doxygen_bug_test.zip )

Generate pdf file from the doxygen latex output, look at the latest page, latest line: "Definition in file test.h", where "test.h" is a dead link (a link that actually brings me at the top of the document)

You can check the resulting pdf file here: http://dfrank.ru/usr/tmp/refman.pdf

Steps to reproduce (tested on Linux Mint 13 with Doxygen 1.8.8 installed) :

- download and unpack archive in some folder, `cd` to it
- execute the following commands:

---

```
$ cd <folder_where_archive_unpacked>
$ doxygen test_doxyfile
$ cd output/latex
$ make
```

- open generated file `refman.pdf`
- look at the latest page, latest line: "Definition in file test.h", where "test.h" is a dead link (a link that actually brings me at the top of the document)

Comment: I tried a simple example but was not able to reproduce it, used the standard Doxyfile with SOURCE_BROWSER and LATEX_SOURCE_BROWSER set to yes. Can you give some more information how to reproduce this problem (or file a bug report with a complete example in bugzilla)?

Comment: @albert Thanks for your attention, I've updated my question

Comment: By the way, there's no option `LATEX_SOURCE_BROWSER` in doxygen 1.8.8, what have you meant instead?

Comment: my typo should have been LATEX_SOURCE_CODE, sorry. In the mean time I saw you filed a nice small and clean bug report for this (Bug 738548 - latex: dead links to source code, https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738548) and in the mean time I pushed a proposed solution to github.

Comment: oh, thanks! It's quite strange that my bugreport succeed: I tried twice, and I've got like 'connection error' both times. So there are probably two identical bugreports there =)

Comment: I found only 1 bug report.